# AndroidManifest used-sdk minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion not recognized

Tags: android, android-emulator, backwards-compatibility

In my android manifest just before < / manifest> I've set:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

When I run my Android App it gives me this warning:
[2012-03-15 09:51:19 - App] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2012-03-15 09:51:19 - App] Device API version is 15 (Android 4.0.3)

The AVD only shows me emulators with Android versions compatible with the project build target, but what I want to see are all emulators from minSdkVersion 10.

This 'wanted' behavior only happened the first time I ran the project (after computer reboot).

Anyone familiar with this behavior?

Comment: can you try to remove `android:targetSdkVersion` this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who came across the same issue (I hope that I'm not the only one ;))

It's really simple; just detach your real device (if attached) when you want to see all emulators. (Still to me this is weird behavior, at least at an option to show all emulators).

Answer (score 2):

ONE tag, not two:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Comment: Thanks! How easy can it be. I had that before but saw a different example using two items. Still the problem remains that I can't select a lower version emulator. Any clue?

Comment: I've never noticed any filtering of emulators in the AVD list. In my current project my minsdkversion is 8, but the AVD list includes all versions back to 4